# Jquery ajax get request to aspx web method not hitting the breakpoint in the method and error is json parse failed

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public static string getJsonString()
    {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.name = "Alex";
        p.address = "UK";
        string jsonString;
        jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p);

        return jsonString;
    }

}



$("#clickme").on('click', function () {
          $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url: "JsonPage.aspx/getJsonString",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",


                success: function (response) {
                    debugger;

                    $("#name").text(response.d.name);
                    $("#address").text(response.d.address);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                    var msg = '';
                    if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                        msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
                    } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                        msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
                    } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                        msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
                    } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                        msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
                    } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                        msg = 'Time out error.';
                    } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                        msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
                    } else {
                        msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
                    }
                    alert(msg);
                }
            })
        })
    });
```

i am trying to call webmethod using jquery ajax type:"GET", First problem is But breakpoint in the method not hitting. and second in the browser i am getting  error "requested json parse failed".What to do please help...

Comment: remove   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" from your request, that is useful only if your sending some data to server like for POST

Comment: You need to parse the ajax response: `var person = JSON.parse(response.d)`

Comment: ok, i've made this change. problem still there. actually parsing is second problem. first problem is, webmethod not hitting. i dont know why.

Comment: Just to be sure, your `clickme` function is in `$(document).ready(function () {`?

Comment: yes, it is inside jQuery ready function.

Comment: Are you hitting the `$("#clickme").on('click'` function and your `success` or `error` ajax callback?

Comment: krlzlx, yes it is hitting the error ajax callback

Comment: What's the message in `jqXHR.responseText` in the `error` callback?

Comment: krlzlx, message is "Requested JSON parse failed."

Answer (score 1):

Change your method from GET to POST in jQuery

```
$("#clickme").on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "Default.aspx/getJsonString",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (response) {
                debugger;
                $("#name").text(response.d.name);
                $("#address").text(response.d.address);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                var msg = '';
                if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                    msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                    msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                    msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
                } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                    msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
                } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                    msg = 'Time out error.';
                } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                    msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
                } else {
                    msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
                }
                alert(msg);
            }
        })
    })
```

and change your web method to

```
 [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false)]
```

Comment: i've made this change but nothing happened.

Comment: Arun Kumar, i've changed get to post as you suggested, but it is not hitting the breakpoints in webmethod.

Comment: Go to your RouteConfig and comment this line:  settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;

Comment: Arun kumar, not hitting breakpoint, still same message "Requested JSON parse failed."

Comment: Have you changed the web method to use httpget false? I have tested this code and working for me

Comment: Arun Kumar, thanks now it is working :) why it was not working with get request i dont know.